# Dual monitor on Ubuntu can't have the same resolution

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I have a desktop with the latest version of ubuntu and windows 10. I have a dual set of monitors, both are technically twins, same brand and same size monitor. I have an nVidia GeForce 8400GS and has 2 VGA ports which I have my monitors plugged in. I have install the Proprietary, Tested Drivers and also install anything else. I can't get to set both at the same resolution which is 1440x900s. My second monitor resolution is always lower around 1280x800 but my first can reach 1440x900. My windows 10 can have both monitors with the same resolution of 1440x900 Please help me set both monitors with the same resolution of 1440x900 so I can finally move on and set linux as my primary OS and eliminate windows for good.

Comment: Could you please paste the contents of `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` (if it exists)? Also, does typing the command `grep NVIDIA /var/log/Xorg.0.log` produce any output? If so could you paste that please?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem only I had Nvidia gts 250 none of the drivers worked for me so this is how I fixed my issue. opened up `xorg.conf` by typing `sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Found the monitor input and set the HorizSync and VertRefresh for my resolution. And everything worked for me after reboot meaning in resolution setting I was able to chose the right resolution for my second monitor.